# 2D x 2D when the rows and columns are set by a user, random

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, random

My task was to write a program that **multiplies two matrices**. The program **should retrieve information from the user how many rows and columns** he has
the first of the matrix and how much the second of the matrix (by which we will multiply). Then enter the range of numbers for the first and second matrices. The tables are filled with random numbers from the given ranges. Then we do the multiplication
matrix. We display matrices filled with random numbers and the resulting matrix. So I did it, but the answer is not right. Can anybody help me out with this stuff ? Many thanks in advance...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  cout << "Provide first matrix dimensions (rows, cols):\n";
  int TWier1, TKol1, za;
  cin >> TWier1 >> TKol1;
  int taba[TWier1][TKol1];
  cout << "Provide matrix max value:\n";
  cin >> za;
  for(int i=0;i<TWier1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol1;j++)
    {
      taba[i][j] = rand() % za;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<TWier1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol1;j++)
    {
      cout << taba[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  cout << "Provide second matrix dimensions (rows, cols):\n";
  int TWier2, TKol2;
  cin >> TWier2 >> TKol2;
  int tabb[TWier2][TKol2];
  for(int i=0;i<TWier2;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      taba[i][j] = rand() % za;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<TWier2;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      cout << tabb[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  int tabc[TWier1][TKol2];
  for(int i=0;i<TWier1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      tabc[i][j]=0;
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<TWier1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      for(int k=0;k<TWier1;k++)
      {
        tabc[i][j] += taba[k][j]*tabb[i][k];
      }
    }
  }
  for(int i=0;i<TWier1;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      cout << tabc[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think that "the answer is not right"?

Comment: `int tabb[TWier2][TKol2];` <-- you use VLAS which is not standard C++; Maybe not related to the question but I would recommend to simply use `std::vector`

Comment: Translating everything to English will make the code more selfexplaining and thereby facilitate helping you.

Comment: Please include input, output and expected output in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in second matrix initialization:

```
  int TWier2, TKol2;
  std::cin >> TWier2 >> TKol2;
  int tabb[TWier2][TKol2];
  for(int i=0;i<TWier2;i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<TKol2;j++)
    {
      taba[i][j] = rand() % za;  <--- here should be tabb instead of taba
    }
  }
```

Otherwise should be OK, unless you want to have different max values for the matrices.

Comment: Well then, Thanks a lot mate ;-)